# Downloading data from S3 amazon public bucket without having AWS access key

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I want to download data from public bucket on S3 amazon server. The bucket is `sentinel-s2-l1c.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com`. I want to access contents of the bucket through my python code without having an AWS account. I cannot login to the AWS account as I don't want to give credit/debit card details to Amazon.

Is there as way of downloading the contents of this bucket without logging in from python code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you make your bucket to public then you can use [wget](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wget) module

to download your file.

Answer (score 1):

If the bucket is public then you can just access the contents using http

The contents are available at the following

http://sentinel-s2-l1c.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com

Comment: Thanks for the answere. But my question was, How to download it using a python code?